# HTML2Canvas works on desktop but not on mobile. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

The point of the website is to download an image of a signed consent form. Everything works how I would like on desktop, but it does not work on mobile unfortunately. I tried chrome, brave, firefox, and safari. I either get the image showing but not downloading, or some weird page distortion. How can I adjust the code to fix it?

this is the source code: 
https://github.com/jacelecomte/wwvhSigns

The methods that deal with the saving of the image are here:

```
function finalizeScreenshot() {
    html2canvas(document.body).then(function (canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        saveScreenshot(canvas);
    });
}

function injectScript(uri) {
    const document = window.document;
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src", uri);
    //document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function injectHtml2canvas() {
    injectScript("//html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js");
}

 injectScript('./src/html2canvas.js');
    injectHtml2canvas();
    finalizeScreenshot();

function saveScreenshot(canvas) {
    const fileName = "Consent Form";
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = fileName + ".png";
    //console.log(canvas);
    canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
        console.log(blob);
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.click();
    });
} 

//these 3 functions are run in a row to create and download the screenshot. 
 injectScript('./src/html2canvas.js');
 injectHtml2canvas();
 finalizeScreenshot();
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the viewport just before calling html2canvas, then change it back afterwards.  This answer was derived from [html2canvas issue fix on github](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1979)

This should fix it:

1: give your <meta name="viewport"../>  an id, like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" id="viewportMeta" />
```

2. revised function

   ```
   function finalizeScreenshot() {
       var vp = document.getElementById("viewportMeta").getAttribute("content");

       document.getElementById("viewportMeta").setAttribute("content", "width=800");

       html2canvas(document.body).then(function (canvas) {        
           document.body.appendChild(canvas);
           saveScreenshot(canvas);
       }).then(function () {
           document.getElementById("viewportMeta").setAttribute("content", vp);
       }); }
   ```

Comment: No need for an id, you can use `$('meta[name="viewport"]')[0].getAttribute("content");`

Comment: This approach helps but, for instance, the paddings between line elements are too big in my case. Same with buttons. It seems that html2canvas has still problems. – Maybe the CSS media queries for mobile screens interfere with the CSS for desktop. – FIX: `$('body').css('width', screenshot_width);`

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to set your own `windowWidth` setting which should trigger the relevant media queries:

```
html2canvas( document.body, {
    windowWidth: '1280px'
} ).then( function( canvas ) {
    document.body.appendChild( canvas );
} );
```

See the available [html2canvas options](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration).